# Group by, summarise and divide by the number of distinct months using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a following data:

```
id  date        value
1   2020-01-22  20
1   2020-03-12  18
1   2020-03-25  16
2   2020-04-22  20
2   2020-04-22  23
```

First I wish group by `id` and `date` and sum values for distinct dates. Then, I want to group by `id` to sum the total value and divide by the count of distinct months from `date`.

The first part is easy. I can simply do: `df.groupby(["id", "date"]).sum()`. I then get the following:

```
                value
id  date        
1   2020-01-22  20
1   2020-03-12  18
1   2020-03-25  16
2   2020-04-22  43
```

But I do not only want to get the aggregate but the sum being divided by the number of unique months in the `date`. My idea for counting the unique months would be: `len(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.to_period('M').unique())`. However, I have no idea how to combine the two together.

Basically, the output I'm looking for is:

```
id  value_after_division
1   27
2   43
```

In simpler terms: 27=(20+18+16)/2 and 43=(43)/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to aggregate "number of unique months" and "total value", and divide them. You already had the latter part. For the former, if only we had a (temporary) column indicating the month. So we go:

```py
# get hold on a grouper object after making month available
g = df.assign(month=df.date.dt.month).groupby("id")

# aggregate
nuniq_mon = g["month"].nunique()
total_val = g["value"].sum()

# div is method way of /
result = total_val.div(nuniq_mon)
```

to get

```py
>>> result

id
1    27.0
2    43.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Worked! I had to add the `pd.to_datetime()` in the first line to make it work: `g = df.assign(month=pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.month).groupby("id")`.

Comment: @bajun65537 yeah actually i did that too :p but assumed you had already done that!